# iframe to external sites

Tags: html, iframe

1. Is it legal to have an IFrame on a website which inside has an external website?
2. In an IFrame is it possible to only show a section of the src that isn't the top left of the site (for instance if there was a chart in the middle of a website, could u have just the chart in your Iframe, or at least start it centred there)
3. Is there any way to stop my IFrame from auto redirecting me to the external site

for 3: ie

```
<iframe src="http://fifa.com"></iframe>
```

Just sends me to fifa instead of actually showing that site in a frame.

Comment: Legal is a strange term to use. Perhaps valid better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This depends on the rules of the external website. You should at least ask them for permission and only do it if they are OK with it (no replay does *not* mean they agree!)
2. No, an IFrame is like a new browser.
3. If the external site uses JavaScript to break out of frames, then the only way to prevent this is to disable JavaScript in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an iframe is it possible to copy the chart and source it back to where you got it from?

Fifa is probably using javascript to prevent you from placing the site in an iframe... and it's generally a pretty shady thing to do.

Comment: Indeed, fifa does:

if(parent.frames.length>0) {
top.location.href=self.location.href;
}

Comment: Dam you FIFA! haha based on the answers to my other questions this wont be my best solution anyways! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

1. I guess it's legal, but it isn't decent.
2. Ah, so you only wanna show the scores i.e., I guess there should be a way, but again it's not decent, you just don't use such constructions, you just don't!
3. No! That's exactly the point of that redirect. The only way to do that will be with javascript disabled.